# ¿Se pueden seguir usando comandos powershell o bash desde un programa de consola Python?

Tags: python, bash, cmd, consola, powershell

La pregunta puede ser confusa, así que lo explico mejor aquí.

Lo que yo pretendo es ejecutar un programa de python, y cuando yo lo permita, permitir al usuario usar los comandos que ya podría conocer de cmd o bash, sin tener que programar cmd o bash desde 0 dentro de mi programa en python, de forma similar a como lo hace git portable.

Cuando abres git portable, no tienes el path configurado con la ubicación de git, y sin embargo te abre una consola, permitiendo usar los comandos cmd o bash, y sólo necesitas añadir el comando "git" al principio para dar órdenes a git en el directorio que estás navegando en consola.

Dicho de otra forma, me gustaría abrir cmd o bash en python, y añadir un comando para pasarle argumentos a mi programa. Por ejemplo en cmd podría verse como:

```
C:\Users\Usuario>cd documents
C:\Users\Usuario\Documents>dir
Directorio de C:\Users\Usuario\Documents

01/10/2023  10:29    <DIR>          .
30/07/2021  13:13    <DIR>          carpeta
23/12/2022  20:30               127 archivo.txt
etc. etc.

C:\Users\Usuario\Documents>cd carpeta
C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\carpeta>miprograma -new nombredearchivo.extensión
C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\carpeta>miprograma -open nombredearchivo.extensión
Bienvenido a mi programa!
Presiona "e" para salir
e
C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\carpeta>
```

De momento sé como pasar argumentos a mi programa desde consola con "sys.argv", pero para que me sea útil, tendría escribir la dirección de mi programa cada vez que quiera hacer cualquier cosa con él, o configurar el path para añadir mi programa, resultando muy poco práctico.

Gracias, espero sus respuestas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lograr esto, puedes utilizar el módulo subprocess de Python, que te permite ejecutar comandos del sistema operativo desde tu programa en Python. Para lograr esto, puedes utilizar el módulo subprocess de Python, que te permite ejecutar comandos del sistema operativo desde tu programa en Python. Es basico , igual lo tendras que adaptar:

```
import subprocess

while True:
    command = input("$ ")
    if command.startswith("miprograma"):
        # Aquí puedes manejar los comandos específicos de tu programa
        args = command.split()
        if args[1] == "-new":
            print(f"Creando nuevo archivo: {args[2]}")
        elif args[1] == "-open":
            print(f"Abriendo archivo: {args[2]}")
        # Añade aquí más comandos si los necesitas
    elif command == "exit":
        break
    else:
        # Si el comando no es específico de tu programa, se ejecuta en la línea de comandos
        process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
        print(stdout.decode('utf-8'))
```